# parse ordered dictionary python

Tags: python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I have an ordered Dictionary:

```
OrderedDict = 
([('time', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '15', '30', '60', '90']), ('uom', ['kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa'])])
```

I have a list of gherkin steps:

```
List =
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "<uom>"\n', 'And Device is set to value "<time>"\n']
```

**How can i iterate the ordered dictionary so that I can replace "uom" and "time" in the list with values in the ordered dictionary?**

Output I want is this:

```
iteration 1: 
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value 'kpa'\n', 'And Device is set 
to value '1'\n']

iteration 2: 
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value 'kpa'\n', 'And Device is set 
to value '2'\n']

...

iteration 10: 
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value 'kpa'\n', 'And Device is set 
to value '90'\n']
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I removed the tags irrelevant for your question. Only tag whats important - neiter of the removed has any relevance.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Havin and ordered dict is not important for your task, a simple one is sufficient. An ordered dict is important if you want to get the keys in the same order you stuffed them into the dict.

You just need the lists of the two keys in question, [zip(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) theire value-lists to pairs and print the text-replacement:

```
# simple dict
od = {'time': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '15', '30', '60', '90'], 
      'uom': ['kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa']}

# your text
texts = ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "<uom>"\n', 'And Device is set to value "<time>"\n']

someList = []

# zip the correlating uom/time/ppm together and iterate them
for tup in zip(od["uom"],od["time"]):
    # create a partial list for this iteration and replace the placeholders
    part = [texts[0].replace("<uom>",tup[0]), texts[1].replace("<time>",tup[1])]
    print(part)

# for good measure: stuff into full list
    someList.append(part)

# print full list
print(someList)
```

Output:

```
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "1"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "2"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "3"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "4"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "5"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "10"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "15"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "30"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "60"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "90"\n']

[['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "1"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "2"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "3"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "4"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "5"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "10"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "15"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "30"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "60"\n'], 
 ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device is set to value "90"\n']
]
```

Sidenote: your output is not really feasible as you need to switch the `'` to '"' if you use them inside a string - or the other way round. You can have

```
["some text 'some other' things"] # or
['some text "some other" things'] # or
# you mask them out by
['some text \'some other\' things']
```

---

If you do not have the keys up front, you can use dict.keys() to get them. Like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict([('time', ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10', '15', '30', '60', '90']), 
      ('uom', ['kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa', 'kpa']),
      ('ppm', ['009','019','029','039','049','059','069','079','089','099'])])

# your text
texts = ['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "<uom>"\n', 'And Device <ppm> is set to value "<time>"\n']

# zip the correlating uom/time together and iterate them
part = [texts[0], texts[1]] # templated text
keys = list(od.keys()) # all the keys
for tup in zip(*od.values()): # all the value tuples (in key order)
    for idx,val in enumerate(tup):
        corrKey = '<'+keys[idx]+'>'  # get corresponding key as replace text
        part[0] = part[0].replace(corrKey,val) # replace it in both parts
        part[1] = part[1].replace(corrKey,val) # of your text

    print(part)
    # reset to template text    
    part = [texts[0], texts[1]]
```

Output:

```
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 009 is set to value "1"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 019 is set to value "2"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 029 is set to value "3"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 039 is set to value "4"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 049 is set to value "5"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 059 is set to value "10"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 069 is set to value "15"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 079 is set to value "30"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 089 is set to value "60"\n']
['Given Device unit of measure is set to value "kpa"\n', 'And Device 099 is set to value "90"\n']
```

Comment: Or: `''.join([''.join(li).replace('<uom>',uom).replace('<time>',t) for t,uom in zip(od['time'],od['uom'])])`

Comment: @PatrickArtner What about if the keys of the dictionary are not known and size of the steps are not known?